# GitLab with docker-compose throwing wierd errors

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
networks:
  traefik_network:
    external: true
 
services:
  gitlab:
    container_name: gitlab
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'my-server'
    environment:
      GITLAB_HOME: ./srv/gitlab
      # GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      #   external_url 'https://my-server'
      #   # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
    ports:
      - '3380:80'
      - '3443:443'
      - '3322:22'
    volumes:
      - ./srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - ./srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - ./srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '256m'
    networks:
      - traefik_network
```

I started with this guide as it seemed to be the most recent thing I could find.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose

I changed my volume directory after trying chmod and guessing that the issue I was having might be related to file permissions.  Changing my volume to the same directory as the project did not make a difference.  Other than that I am pretty much the same as the default recommended file.  I need to get this to eventually run with SSL and NGINX but I'd like to start with just getting the app running.  Does anyone have a working docker file or know what is causing my errors?

This is first chunk of my output:

https://pastebin.com/mtzYWFDg

As you can see after it gets through the start up stuff, it begins to loop every second and start complaining about owners and symlinks and execute ruby blocks.  This looping errors won't stop until I kill the container.  The ports are also unreachable.  I have no idea what I could have done to cause any of those errors and I'm pretty lost trying to find answers.

Comment: You don't seem to have included the actual `docker-compose.yml`, the output, or any other relevant code in your question.  Can you [edit] the question and make sure these details are included directly in the question and not behind links?  Is any of your own code involved, or are you just trying to deploy GitLab?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have edited the post to include my docker-compose.yml directly, but the code output it pretty long, I don't konw if it's a good idea to post it here.  Can you open the pastebin for the output log?

Yes I am simply trying to just deploy gitlab.  The only edits that are "my code" are small changes like the ports since I already have something running on 80/443 and other small tweaks in an effort to get the default image deployed.  I am trying to figure out what piece I'm missing.